# ¿Como puedo mostrar una descripción corta de un campo personalizado de un Custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

Esto que tengo es el que utilizo para blog he intentado modificar este para el CPT pero me muestra todo el contenido del Campo personalizado.

```
function ramblaprim_get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
/* $excerpt = preg_replace(" ([.*?])",'',$excerpt); */
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 205);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
return $excerpt;
```

}

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas `get_the_excerpt()` simplemente? Algo así: **`function ramblaprim_get_excerpt(){ return get_the_excerpt(); }`** Supongo que has agregado una descripción corta (excerpt) a tus posts. Si no lo has hecho deberías, por cuestiones de SEO y demás, y porque te va a simplificar labores como estas. [Mira este enlace](https://www.deiverbum.org/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/san-mateo/), si pones el puntero sobre cualquiera de los enlaces de la lista verás una descripción breve que se hace usando `get_the_excerpt` sin tener que reinventar la rueda.

Answer (score -1):

Ya conseguí la solución, es que para los CPT se tenia que usar una función diferente. no servia la misma del blog. esto fue lo que hice:

```
function get_excerpt_ramblaprim($description) {
$new_description = get_field($description);
$description_corta = mb_substr($new_description, 0, 205);

$output = '';
$output .= '<p class="mb-5">' . $description_corta . '</p>';

echo $output;}
```

y luego la desplegué de la siguiente manera.

```
<p class="mb-5"><?php get_excerpt_ramblaprim('contenido') ?></p>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas las funciones propias de Wordpress, en este caso [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)? Como lo estás haciendo el código no queda optmizado: 1º porque lo que obtienes no es realmente un excerpt, 2º porque traes datos de más para luego desechar una parte de ellos. Ambas cosas tienen consecuencias en el rendimiento, en el SEO y en la estética. Por ejemplo, al cortar de forma arbitraria a 205 caracteres, vas a tener una descripción recortada sin ningún control.

Comment: Lo siento no soy un experto, yo desarrollo de manera autodidacta aunque estoy en constante formación, pero no como no me funciono la de wordpress busque otra alternativa...